# Trying to convert DateTime + a timezone to DateTimeOffset of the local timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to convert a hardcoded DateTime to a DateTimeOffset but localized to the provided timezone.

Given the hardcoded DateTime of: `DateTime someUtcDateTime = new(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);` and a timezone of  "America/New_York" I get back the result: `2022-01-01 12:00:00 -05:00`

I thought the answer should be: `2022-01-01 7:00:00 -05:00`

Am I incorrect in my expected answer?

Here's the C# code I was attempting:

(Note: I'm referencing the `TimeZoneConverter` nuget package to help me out)

```
        public static DateTimeOffset ToLocalDateTimeOffset(
            this DateTime utcDateTime,
            string? locationTimeZone,
            string defaultTimezoneIfNoneProvided = CommonConstants.SYDNEY_TIMEZONE)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(defaultTimezoneIfNoneProvided))
            {
                throw new Exception("Default timezone must be provided.");
            }

            var timeZone = GetTimeZoneInfo(locationTimeZone, defaultTimezoneIfNoneProvided);

            // Convert the provided utc time into the local time.
            var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, timeZone);

            // Now convert the local time to a DateTimeOffset.
            var localDateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(utcDateTime, timeZone.GetUtcOffset(utcDateTime));

            return localDateTimeOffset;
        }

    public static class DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers
    {
        public static readonly DateTime SomeUtcDateTime = new(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);

        public const string NewYorkTimeZone = "America/New_York";

        public const string SydneyTimezone = CommonConstants.SYDNEY_TIMEZONE;

        public static TimeSpan ToUtcOffset(string timeZoneId)
        {
            var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

            return timezone.GetUtcOffset(SomeUtcDateTime);
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ToLocalDateTime_GivenATimeZone_ShouldReturnALocalDateTimeForTheProvidedTimeZone()
    {
        // Arrange
        var utcOffset = DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers.ToUtcOffset(DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers.NewYorkTimeZone);

        var expectedDateTime = DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers.SomeUtcDateTime + utcOffset;

        // Act
        var result = DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers.SomeUtcDateTime.ToLocalDateTime(
            DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers.NewYorkTimeZone, 
            DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers.SydneyTimezone);

        // Assert
        result.ShouldBe(expectedDateTime);
    }
```

Comment: You didn't set the `DateTime.Kind` - not sure though if that would make a difference here.

Comment: im not familiar with `DateTimeExtensionTestHelpers` but why you put there both Timezones (Sydney and New york)? The output you got would be the way you have it now if there was 2 conversions, firstly to new york, and then to sydney time (or vice versa), and it looks like it.

Comment: What does `ToLocalDateTime` do? Where is `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: Ahh sorry @shingo - yeah, my main method I'm testing. i've updated the OP.

Comment: Shameless plug: in my Noda Time library (https://nodatime.org) library, it would be harder to go wrong. How feasible would it be for you to use that?

Comment: feasible, for sure - i've just never used it?

Comment: Shameless recomendation: ^^ it's worth to look into, _really_. (talking about Noda)

Comment: Your comment said "Now convert the **local time** to a DateTimeOffset", but the name of your first parameter is **utc**DateTime. The comment is right, the parameters represent a local time and its offset to UTC.

Comment: @shingo - That looks indeed to be the problem.  You should provide that as an answer. :)